# Which mode to configure MP24833AGN LED driver when we need output voltage higher than input voltage?

Tags: led, driver

The MP24833AGN is a good choice for an LED driver when we have a DC input of 9 or 12 V (or even higher) and need to drive bright LEDs which consume high current like 1A or more.

If your application is boost type, ensure that you use the buck-boost mode rather than dedicated boost mode.

This is because in boost mode the LEDs will glow even when the IC is disabled via Enable pin if the input voltage falls under the combined forward voltage range of the LED string.

If we use buck-boost mode, this issue can be avoided and the switching be enabled and LED string circuit be completed only when the IC is enabled usig EN pin.

[image: Boost Configuration]

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere? If so, ask it. Otherwise... should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in boost mode the LEDs will glow even when the IC is disabled via Enable pin if the input voltage falls under the combined forward voltage range of the LED string.
If we use buck-Boost Mode, this issue can be avoided and the switching be enabled and LED string circuit be completed only when the IC is enabled usig EN pin.
Thanks. Take Care.